# In Excel, I need to add a zero to the beginning of a number if it begins with 1, but not if it begins with 3

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of numbers. Some begin with a 3 and don’t need to be changed; others begin with a 1 and require a zero added to the beginning. I have this formula that was supplied to add the zero:

```
="0"&left(A2,20)
```

but I need to apply this only to the numbers starting with a 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: Adding a 0 - is this text?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="1",CONCATENATE("0",A2),A2)
```

Copy and drag to the other cells.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
=IF(LEFT($A2,1)="1","0"&left($A2,20),$A2)
```

The "IF" is just to check that the first character on the left is "1"